# creating a web base app for google drive

Tags: .net, google-drive-api

I want to create a web base application that in .net c# using google drive to storage videos and pictures that is sharable among an organization. I want to be able to add metadata to files uploaded or edited to help make searchable. Is it possible to create an application like this? and is there any good resources?

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible to write a web application that stores files to Google Drive and manages their sharing permissions.

A good starting point is the example ASP.NET MVC application that is included in the Google Drive SDK documentation:

https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/dotnet

Comment: Is there a way or example to do it without MVC.

Comment: Even if it is an ASP.NET MVC sample, the code for the Drive API logic can be used in any other project. Another sample available is a command-line one: https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart

Comment: I'm not understanding how to make the call to oAuth to authentic to use google drive api